# Non equal phase currents at nominal speed vector control Permanent magnet synchronous motor

Tags: pwm, three-phase, dsp, matlab, pmsm

[image: Phase currents in stacionary state]
I working on my implementation of vector control for PMSM.
I'm having close loops over speed, current in d axis(flux loop), current in q axis(torque loop). I'm using MATLAB/Simulink for vector control algorithm, X2C makes communication with DSP from Texas Instruments Delphino TMS320F28335. [HVPFC KIT](http://www.ti.com/tool/TMDSHVMTRPFCKIT) is used as a driver or a motor. 
I'm trying to improve phase currents wave forms. These are also dq currents with they referencies in stacionary state. 
[image]
[image]
At rated speed machine is turning at 3000 rpm, where current frequencies are 200Hz. I tried to move moment when currents are sampled, changed max voltage duty cycle. Tried to speed up current regulators. 
Nothing helps, any suggestions?

Comment: correctly tune your loops.

Comment: [link](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/motordrivecontrol/archive/2015/07/20/teaching-your-pi-controller-to-behave-part-i) used this method for parameter setup but I'll try to change ok.

Comment: The phase currents appear to be equal, but the amplitude is oscillating. Looks like a tuning problem to me.

Comment: I'm trying but can't get amplitudes steady...